# Git fsck --unreachable --lost-found does not save objects as files at the lost-found directory

Tags: git, git-fsck

I used `fsck` and found that I have some dangling objects, and more than that (in amount) unreachable objects.

`fsck --lost-found` does save the dangling objects as files at the `lost-found` directory, but when I want for it to write all unreachable objects with `fsck --unreachable --lost-found` it does not write them, so I end up missing some unreachable objects.

Why does that happen and is there a way for Git to write those unreachable objects as well into files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:
`--lost-found` supports only dangling objects, according to the Git documentation:

> --lost-found
>   Write dangling objects into .git/lost-found/commit/ or .git/lost-found/other/, depending on type. If the object is a blob, the contents are written into the file, rather than its object name.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck#Documentation/git-fsck.txt---lost-found